# mod_rewrite Adds .php Extension When Accessing Site Without www. Prefix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The issue that I am having is that when I try to access my site without the www. prefix, the .php extension is added to the address, which can often cause a problem. For example, if I try to access my homepage with the address example.com, that address is transformed into www.example.com/.php. I want the www. to be added, but the .php extension added at the end just causes an error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with your last line.  Mod Rewrite does not stop after executing the first rule.  Try adding the last rule modifier to the redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If I add the L, how do I get something like mysite.com/main to resolve to www.mysite.com/main.php? Wouldn't stopping at the above line prevent the .php from being resolved?

Comment: The RewriteRule on line 4 is under a RewriteCond so it wont fire unless that condition passes.  So, after the redirect from example.com to www.example.com that rule will get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell apache to stop processing rules after the 301 redirect, do this by adding an L - e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

aside: you'd get on better if you enabled multiviews on the first line, and removed the  last 3 lines ;)

Comment: compare your line 4 with the above line, and you should see the added L

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how I do this: "you'd get on better if you enabled multiviews on the first line, and removed the last 3 lines"

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from .htaccess and try..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```